# What is a difference in lifecycle between 'entity' object and function object in javascript?

Tags: closures, javascript-objects

Why does this code snippet outputs 5 (as expected due to scope chain) ?

```
let arr = []
var firstFunc;
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var iterFunc = function () {
        return function() {
            return i
        }
    }
    arr.push(iterFunc())
}

console.log(arr[0]())
```

but this outputs {a: 0}:

```
let arr = []
var firstFunc;
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var iterFunc = function () {
        return {
            a: i
        }
    }
    arr.push(iterFunc())
}

console.log(arr[0])
```

what memory allocation logic occurs under the hood ? Why 'entity' object persists current value in contrast to closure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning `i` or `{a: i}` here doesn't matter.

The important thing is that in first example, `iterFunc()` returns a function and is inside that (not yet invoked) function where `i` or `{a: i}` is evaluated.

Having `i` is always holding a scalar (immutable) value, that value is what you get in place. (If `i` would have been an object, a reference to that object would be returned and if, its contents mutated, you could see that mutations).

Being immutable value, you will get that value. But, as you know, `i` value changes in time, so the key thing here is **WHEN** that value is read.

If you see at your first example, in `console.log(...)` statement, you are **intentionally** invoking it as the function you know it is (the unnamed function returned by `iterFunc()`) and, that time, `i` is holding a value of `5`.

If, in your first example, you just change following line:

```
arr.push(iterFunc())
```

by

```
arr.push(iterFunc()())
```

...and, of course:

```
console.log(arr[0]())
```

by

```
console.log(arr[0]) // Same of your second example.
```

You will realize that output will be the same in both cases (0).